# Strange probability question found in book

Tags: probability

I have seen  one question in book and I suppose that it is not correct, question is following :

> If a family has three children, find the probability that two of the three children are girls.

To be honest  this question is similar  to the following question : if in the class there are $30$ student and there is $10$ George, find the probability that  randomly selected student's name will be George is not similar? I know   term sample space, but in any case answer should be  $\frac23$ right? but book says   $\frac38$ because   if  we  select  children's in   sequence we will have following possible combinations

BBB, BBG, BGB, GBB, GGG, GGB, GBG, and BGG.

Which one is correct?

Comment: The book is correct, and your example is not similar, because you know how many George, but not how many girls.

Comment: aa that is point i wanted to know ,  about  unknown number of  something is different  thanks for answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the probability of having a boy or a girl is $0.5$ each, you need to consider that there are $\binom{3}{2}$ possible ways of having $2$ girls and $1$ boy:

$$P(\mbox{2 girls and 1 boy}) = \binom{3}{2}p_{GIRL}^2\cdot p_{BOY}=3\cdot 0.5^3 = \frac{3}{8}$$

Comment: using binomial distribution yes  , but  in general someone may say that  hey out of three  children probability of two girl will be 2/3 because we have  three  children and two should be girl, that why i was confused about this

Comment: @datodatuashvili : Then you should tell the one who is saying this: Throw a fair coin $3$ times. What is the probability of having two heads and one tail?

Comment: thanks  for  information, that is clear, of  course i can  say : try to make 3  children and see probability :D :D :D :D

Comment: Yeah! :-D Perfect example!!!

Comment: In addtion, about that "2 out of 3" logic: Are those people willing to bet money that of somebody's 10 grandkids all 10 are girls. Because, hey: 10/10. In addition, in the original example, how would they guess the probability would be for 2 boys. If they say "also 2/3", then we have  already two exluding events with sum of probabilities > 1. If they say something other than "2/3", why the difference.